# ¿Por qué no hay "clases" en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Como es bien sabido, JavaScript (ej. node.js: lado del servidor o angular.js), no hacen uso de clases, como en Java o Python.

Pero... ¿Cuál es el motivo por el que JavaScript no tiene clases?

P.S: Ahora JavaScript no es un lenguaje de script. Ahora es un lenguaje del todo, ya que podemos utilizar patrones como el MVC.

Comment: ¿Ahora Js no es un lenguaje de script? ¿Se compila? ¿No usa un interprete? ¿Que tiene que ver todo esto con los patrones?

Comment: En JavaScript sí hay _clases_ ([referencia](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Classes)). La verdad es que la pregunta parece una serie de sentencias (algunas erróneas) y no una pregunta en sí.

Comment: Javascript sí se compila. Hace rato que dejó de ser un lenguaje interpretado.

Comment: En node.js actual si hay clases (incluso en la versión 4 LTS actual) `class` define clases en forma similar (no igual) que los demás lenguajes

Comment: Con respecto a angular, en su versión 2 recomiendan el uso de TypeScript que es el lenguaje diseñado por Microsoft para agregar la misma "**Azúcar**" sintáctica  (mensionada por @Emilio ) que le falta a javascript. TypeScript es un lenguaje que es "compilado" a javascript plano el cual es soportado por todos los navegadores. recomiendo que si vienes de un lenguaje Como Java y/o C# inicies de una con TypeScript.

Comment: Ya que la pregunta está cerrada no puedo contestar, pero diré que JavaScript es un lenguaje orientado a prototipos, que es otra forma de orientación a objetos diferente a las clases. Dado que en general no es una forma muy conocida siempre ha habido presión (como demuestra esta pregunta) para que JavaScript incluya clases (aunque se pueden hacer cosas parecidas) en el último estándar se ha incluido una forma de clases.

Comment: Es importante remarcar que realmente no se agregaron clases, se agregò azùcar sintàtico. Y para nada es una pràctica recomendable para los que ingresan al lenguaje comenzar utilizando clases.

@HónorSalinas  No creo que sea recomendable iniciar con TypeScript. Yo creo que es necesario conocer bien JavaScript, para luego saber què ocurre debajo de TS.

Comment: Javascript no tiene clases porque tiene prototipos. Porque no se usó la palabra reservada `class` hasta hace tan poco puedes leer [aquí](http://javascript.crockford.com/popular.html) algunos detalles de su creación que explican porqué algunas cosas no están concebidas como en los demas lenguajes.

Comment: @EmilioGrisolía javascript no se compila, es un lenguaje interpretado

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Te confundiste de Emilio. Le querías hablar a EmilioPlatzer vos.

Por otro lado... aunque no sea prudente mantener el debate dado el nivel del usuario que preguntó, JavaScript hoy día se compila. Originalmente, y durante mucho tiempo, si, hubo un intérprete.

En realidad, puede ser interpretado o compilado, hoy se ve mas compilación que interpretación...

Answer (score 26):

Vamos por partes. JavaScript es un lenguaje de **scripting**, un *lenguaje de programación típicamente interpretado*. El código que vos escribas en JavaScript, va a ser traducido a lenguaje máquina mediante un **intérprete**, el intérprete mas conocido es la **V8** (un engine en realidad, pero vamos a mentir un poco para mantener las cosas simples) de Google.

Ahora bien, que un lenguaje sea interpretado, o que involucre un paso de compilación (o mas) como en el caso de Java o C++, no lo vuelve menos lenguaje. Los lenguajes típicamente interpretados tienen determinadas ventajas y desventajas frente a lenguajes típicamente compilados.

Por otro lado, cuando nombrás clases, te referís a un **paradigma de programación**. Un paradigma determina una manera de enfocar la resolución de un problema. Java, por ejemplo, es un lenguaje orientado a objetos. Te plantea que enfoques la resolución de los problemas mediante la utilización de objetos que interactúan entre si.

La programación orientada a objetos no es la única manera de programar que existe. También existe, por ejemplo, la programación funcional, en la cuál, el "bloque básico" de construcción, son la funciones. Por ejemplo, el lenguaje Haskell es un lenguaje puramente funcional.

Pero también hay casos como Python, JavaScript y C++, que son lenguajes multiparadigma, ya que te permiten resolver problemas utilizando diferentes enfoques (POO, programación imperativa, programación funcional).

JavaScript te permite enfocar la solución de los problemas mediante -y entre otras opciones- la **programación orientada a prototipos**. Es similar a la programación orientada a objetos; si es una rama dentro de la misma o no, creo que queda fuera de este tópico.

Recientemente, con la última versión del nuevo estándar de JavaScript (ECMAScript 6), se agregó algo que se le dice "azúcar sintáctico", por encima de esta programación orientada a prototipos, que confunde a programadores novatos o que vienen de lenguajes como Java:

```
class MiClase {
   constructor (x, y) {
     this.x = x;
     this.y = y;
   }

   saludar (nombre) {
     console.log(´Hola, ${nombre}! has dicho que x es ${this.x} e y es ${this.y};
   }
}

const mi_objeto = new MiClase(5, 6);
mi_objeto.saludar('Sarasa');
```

Pero nada te fuerza a vos, como programador -y por ende, nada fuerza a los programadores que desarrollan Angular- a utilizar nada de esto. JavaScript no tuvo clases porque no tiene por qué tenerlas, de la misma manera que Haskell ni siquiera tiene bucles *for*. Cada lenguaje te dice "yo te propongo que los problemas los enfoques, mas o menos, de esta manera". Está en vos de qué manera elegís programar.

Por otro lado, MVC es un patrón de "arquitectura", es decir, un patrón de organización de una aplicación/proyecto, en la cuál te dicen que la interfaz tiene que estar separada de la lógica, y a su vez, separada de los modelos que te permiten acceder a los datos. Hay diferentes variantes de este patrón, y no tiene nada que ver con paradigmas de programación en si, ya que separar de esa manera (o manera similar) los componentes de un programa es una noción bastante común que se le presenta a cualquier programador medianamente experimentado. Podés utilizar el patrón MVC sin siquiera usar una clase.

Actualmente en NodeJS, podés utilizar el azúcar sintáctico para crear "clases" (debajo siguen siendo prototipos! :O ). Siempre fue "un lenguaje del todo", y lo seguirá siendo, como cualquier otro lenguaje de programación. Tiene sus cosas buenas, y cosas malas.

Comment: buena explicación y actitud ⁺1.

Comment: @Emilio En cuanto a "*La calidad tècnica del contenido*" me pareció excelente y voté +1. Pero contestando a lo último que agregastes, es el estilo que se busca acá: "**No uses firmas, taglines, o [saludos](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/behavior).**". La idea es ir al grano y evitar texto que no sea la respuesta en sí. No es sólo el autor de la pregunta a quien le estás escribiendo, somos muchos más. Y si te parecía que había que agregar que cualquier duda te avise, eso podía ir en un comentario. Espero que se entienda, pero si no, se puede discutir en [meta]. Te mando un abrazo ;-)

Comment: @Mariano leì eso, y entiendo que dice "saludos", pero te cito: "Cada aporte que hagas ya esta “firmado” con tu tarjeta de usuario en tu perfil. Esta tarjeta forma un enlace permanente a tu pagina de usuario. Si usas una firma adicional o un tagline, sera removida a debido que creará mas ruido en las respuestas y preguntas.". Yo a partir de eso entiendo que puedo saludar, ademàs no me sale no saludar, es como.. ¿por què no?... igual ahì lo edito, un poco me calentè pero tenès razòn... no iba para un edit ;)

Comment: Según mi opinión **Javascript no es un lenguaje interpretado**. Por lo menos no en el sentido en que figura en esta definición https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Int%C3%A9rprete_(inform%C3%A1tica) Que la compilación sea automática y no veamos el compilado (que queda en una caché) no lo hace menos compilado. Si fuera interpretado podría correr aunque tuviera errores de sintaxis en las lineas que aún no se han interpretado y eso no ocurre. (tampoco lo es php ni otros similares de tipos dinámicos)

Comment: No me pareciò en lo mas mìnimo prudente meterle de por medio un debate con un nivel de detalle tan profundo a una persona que aùn no adquiriò la experiencia necesaria para darse cuenta que un lenguaje de programaciòn "no es menos lenguaje o mas lenguaje que otro por no poder implementar el patròn MVC".

Aclarè que es un lenguaje "tìpicamente interpretado", porque JavaScript no està limitado sòlo a los engine modernos tipo V8 y SpiderMonkey; ademàs originalmente era interpretado. Sin contar que la condiciòn de "lenguaje de scripting" no depende de los patrones de arquitectura.

Answer (score 7):

Para responder a la pregunta. primero como mensionan en los comentarios actualmente javascript si soporta el uso de [clases](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Classes) pero estas fueron introducidas en 2015 como dice en la página de mozilla:

> This is a new technology, part of the ECMAScript 2015 (ES6) standard.

por lo que las clases no fueron soportadas en javascript hasta 2015, e incluso hay exploradores (saliendo de los principales, chrome, ffox, opra, etc) que no soporta a plenitud este estandar.

Y **antes de eso, si javascript no tenia clases**, y **el motivo (respondiendo a tu pregunta)** viene dada porque fue un lenguage diseñado no para hacer grandes programas, sino por el contrario fue un lenguaje pensado para agregar cierto tipo de dinamismo a las páginas webs, como por ejemplo menús, efectos de transiciones, validaciones de clientes y operaciones sencillas que no ameritaba gran complejidad. por lo que en su diseño no se vio la necesidad de permitir el uso **directo** de la orientación a objetos ( podía ser emulada ), y durante muchos años continuo así.

Pero el tiempo fue pasando y en el mundo actual javascript se a vuelto uno de los lenguajes más importantes en el diseño web, realmente se están creando aplicaciones y soluciones completas en el lado del cliente, Gráficos, Juegos, Motores 3d, etc, etc, etc, todo lo que quieras hacer. I también pasó lo que a muchos sorprendió **javascript** llega al servidor, ***el mundo vio nacer a*** **nodejs**, y bueno no está en mi explicar que es porque esa no es la pregunta. pero la cuestión es que **permite ejecutar javascript en el servidor** y lo que permitio al lenguaje unirse a los viejos dominantes de ese mundo como lo son PHP, Java, c#, python, etc. Lo que en los últimos años lo ha vuelto muy popular.

como dice la gran frase

> ### un gran poder conlleva una gran responsabilidad

Y con la responsabilidad viene **la necesidad de crear aplicaciones más complejas, escalables, estables, seguras y para resumir robustas usando javascript**, es necesario que el lenguaje se nutra y pues la orientación a objetos a permitido esto por años, siendo uno de los paradigmas predominantes en la programación. por lo que que se busca actualmente es enriquecer el lenguaje. lenguajes como TypeScript y CoffeScript son ejemplos del intento de mejorar el lenguaje.

> Y la pregunta del millón porque simplemente no se cambia el lenguaje
>   se usa uno más rico en sintaxis o simplemente mejor, o un lenguaje que ya permita realizar aplicaciones muy robustas?,

Pues porque la idea es que el lenguaje debe ser soportado por todos los navegadores o en su mayoría lo que ha sido una guerra y un dolor de cabeza por muchos años y javascript ya es soportado por la mayoría así que la solución que ha presentado uno de los grandes competidores en este mundo (MCSoft) es hacer un superset de javascript "**TypeScript**". **la solución es simple hagamos un lenguaje que creemos que es mejor y luego lo transformas a javascript plano**, que sea soportado por todos, y todos somos felices, actualmente hay muchas soluciones parecidas, como por ejemplo puedes programar en Golang y Python y hay "compiladores" que te transforma dicho código en javascript plano.

( hay personas que aman javascript, otras simplemente lo odian y esto es muy variado.)

Puedes usar javascript, ( ya hay clases ) o simplemente, aprende a usar TypeScript, o consigue un compilador para el lenguaje que ya manejas y simplemente se feliz suerte.

Answer (score 2):

No hay clases propiamente dichas, pero hay objetos, y se pueden usar para **simular** una clase, por ejemplo:

```js
clase = function(){
 var obj=this;
 obj.propiedadPublica=0;
 obj.metodoPublico = function(txt){metodoPrivado(txt);};
 var propiedadPrivada=1;
 var metodoPrivado = function(txt){
  document.write(txt+propiedadPrivada+", "+obj.propiedadPublica+"<br>");
  propiedadPrivada++;
 };
};
var obj1 = new clase();
var obj2 = new clase();
obj1.propiedadPublica=2;
obj1.metodoPublico("obj1: ");
obj2.metodoPublico("obj2: ");
obj2.propiedadPublica=3;
obj1.metodoPublico("obj1: ");
obj2.metodoPublico("obj2: ");
```

Comment: No entiendo el negativo, si bien es cierto que si existen las clases desde 2015, no están soportadas en todos los navegadores, y hasta ahora se han creado así, esta solución sigue funcionando, y en todos los navegadores.

Answer (score -1):

El concepto de clases, javascript lo maneja a un nivel mucho mayor que la mayoría de los otros lenguajes. No existen desde el punto de vista de la programacion orientada a objetos que se enseña de forma clásica, usando la palabra reservada class ni mucho menos. Javascript posee la capacidad de interpretar una funcion como un constructor. Convencionalmente los programadores acordaron escribir con la inicial mayúscula, aquella función determinada a ser un constructor, por cuestiones de legibilidad. Ahora, existen al igual que en los demás lenguajes, formas de trabajar con los datos internos, incluso de tener campos privados. Si se quiere que la clase tenga un atributo publico, simplemente se declara: `this.propiedad = valor;` o simplemente no se le atribuye un valor (pero es recomendable inicializarlas). Si hace falta un atributo que sea privado, se declara normalmente: `var propiedad = valor;`. Otra cosa muy importante que hace falta mencionar aqui es el caso de los prototipos. Estos sirven para reutilizar código en las funciones. Si creamos un método, éste se va a repetir dentro de cada objeto que hemos creado, sin embargo, usando prototipos, este se crea una sola vez y es utilizado cuando se requiera. Se puede hacer asi: `clase.prototype.miFuncion = function() {...}`. Una bondad que nos da Javascript es la de expandir un objeto de la clase simplemente agregándolo. Por ejemplo, si nuestra clase tiene como atributos, las variables a, b y c, pero yo quiero que mi objeto tenga d, solamente tengo que escribir `obj.d = valor;` y automáticamente se crea la variable d, dentro del objeto.

Comment: La expresión "manejar el concepto de clases a un nivel mucho mayor" no está fundamentada.
Las clases son azúcar sintático sobre los prototipos, para tener miembros privados, leer sobre WeakSets.